# Receiver called when the user is navigating to Home screen android?

Tags: android

I am struggling to find one solution for past some time .i.e I want to show dialog when the user navigates back to home screen after being in any of the position like while using third party app,calling,text.So when he comes back to default home screen ,i need to show a dialog.Is that possible?
Early help is appreciated.

Regards
Shubham jain

Comment: yes did you tried calling dialog picker in onResume(); of home screen.... because when you will come back to the home screen onResume method will be called and you can put the dialog picker in it and your requirement will be done....

Comment: I want to track the default home screen of Android.I dont have my Home activity.Anyways thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code in your onCreate method of home activity and modify as per your requirement.

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

// Setting Dialog Title
alertDialog.setTitle(title);

// Setting Dialog Message
alertDialog.setMessage(message);

if(status != null)
// Setting alert dialog icon

// Setting OK Button
alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    }
});

// Showing Alert Message
alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: I want to track the default home screen of Android.I dont have my Home activity.Anyways thanks for help.

Comment: but you say, you have default home screen.

Comment: Yeah so how do i noe that the user is now present at default home screen.?

Comment: default home screen is decide by your code which is mapped in manifest file. so put above code in default home screen and when user come to this screen alert dialog is opened.

Comment: You are not getting the question i guess.

Comment: I am taking about the device home screen not what i define in menifest.